# How can I see internal server errors for src= endpoints in Flask application

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I'm writing a Dash application, which is a visualization tool that under the hood is a Flask app. I'm trying to render an audio tag, with `src=/assets/audio_data...` in the audio tag. The audio tag renders but doesn't load any audio. When I open the chrome debug console, I can see

> GET http://myserver:8050/assets/audio_data/... 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

How can I debug server errors when they're burried behind a `<audio src=...` URL? For some reason flask seems to be printing practically nothing to the console. Are there more verbose logs/errors in a file somewhere? I am running the app using `run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)` so I expect to see errors in the console but all I see in the console is

```
 * Serving Flask app 'flac_embeddings_scatter_plots'
 * Debug mode: on
```

I know that ordinarily when there's errors in debug mode you see something that looks like this https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#debug-mode, but I don't see it because the URL is being loaded by the `<audio>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to catch all exceptions:

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def all_exception_handler(e):
    error = repr(e)
    print(error)
    return error
```